# Grep for content only if string in above line is different

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I have following content in my log file.

```
abcdefg hijk lmnopq
rstuv wxyz
```

I'm trying to write a command that looks for **wxyz** and writes the 3 lines before and after this search string only if the before line doesn't contain the string **hijk**.

I wrote a grep command but it is not working as it is a line oriented command. Looks like I have to use awk or sed. Any suggestions?

Comment: search for multi-line grep. Duplicate!

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

this does 2 lines before and after, you should be able to change to three...

```
$ awk       '/hijk/{h=NR} 
  /wxyz/&&NR!=(h+1){print p2 ORS p1; w=3} 
                   {p2=p1;p1=$0} 
             w&&w--' file
```

also not handled first line match to wxyz.  For that change to `/wxyz/ && (NR!=(h+1) || !h)` and need to condition printing p2 and p1.

Comment: this command is not showing actual output. can you please explain what this command is doing?

Comment: please post a sample input file to verify the script.